# reason of defining continuous function between two topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology

What is the reason of defining continuous function between two topological spaces ? (is it that under continuous function image of a compact/connected set is compact/connected)

Comment: Think of the special case of continuous functions between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: I want to consider spaces where there is no notion of metric defined. In those cases, under continuous function some nice property gets prserved. Is this the only reason ?

Comment: The "nice property" that you are talking about is exactly the definition a continuous function: inverse images of open sets are open. That definition **generalizes** the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition: a function between two metric spaces satisfies the topological definition of continuity if and only if it satisfies the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. I suggest that you take a look at the opening chapter of a topology book such as Munkres' book "Topology", and pay specific attention to theorems which list various equivalencies between different notions of continuity.

Answer (score 5):

Part of the motivation for introducing the notion of topological space is to provide a "natural" setting for the notion of continuity.  As you wrote, metrics allow you to define continuity.  But they contain way too much information for that purpose. Deforming a space, by stretching and shrinking it, can completely change the metric, yet the continuous functions remain the same as they were.  The topology associated to a metric contains just the information needed in order to specify which functions are continuous.  It is in this sense that topologies provide the "right" context for defining continuity.  (They also provide, in a similar sense, the right context for defining convergence.)

It turns out that topologies and the associated notion of continuity make sense even in situations where no metric is available.  That might be regarded as a side benefit of putting the notion of continuity into the right context.